# How do I select multiple maximum and minimums from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query that has returned a column of numbers and ordered from lowest to highest. I need to display the highest and lowest value. I was planning on using a simple SELECT MAX(x),MIN(x) FROM ... however the table contains multiple minimums and this statement only selects the first minimum.

```
 Example of table
 Name x
 a    1
 b    1
 c    1
 d    2
 e    5
```

How would I display

```
 Name x
 a    1
 b    1
 c    1
 e    5
```

This is just an example, there is a range of rows between the max and min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can JOIN with subquery that return `MIN` and `MAX`. `UNION` will remove duplicates if `MAX = MIN`.

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f21d3/2/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab(Name NVARCHAR(100), x INT);

INSERT INTO tab
VALUES ('a',    1), ('b',    1), ('c',    1), ('d',    2), ('e',    5);

SELECT t.*
FROM tab t 
JOIN (SELECT MIN(x) AS val 
      FROM tab
      UNION
      SELECT MAX(x) AS val
      FROM tab) AS sub
 ON t.x = sub.val;
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use a `join` and aggregation:

```
select e.*
from example e join
     (select min(x) as minx, max(x) as maxx
      from example
     ) em
     on e.x = minx or e.x = maxx;
```

However, if you have an index on `x`, then it may be more efficient to phrase this as:

```
select e.*
from example e
where e.x = (select max(x) from example) union all
select e.*
from example e
where e.x = (select min(x) from example) and
```

Each of the subqueries will make use of the index.  The second does assume that `min(x)` is different from `max(x)`.  This is easily fixed using `union`, but that adds overhead.  Instead:

```
select e.*
from example e
where e.x = (select max(x) from example) union all
select e.*
from example e
where e.x = (select min(x) from example) and
      (select min(x) from example) <> (select max(x) from example);
```

This should continue having efficient use of the index.  And I think the following would also work:

```
where e.x = (select min(x) from example having min(x) <> max(x))
```

Comment: Wow, the second one is pretty clever!

Comment: I guess the only problem with the second query is when `min` is equal to `max`: `UNION ALL` will bring the same rows twice.